# the validity of (ε, δ)-definition of limit

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, epsilon-delta, philosophy

People use this definition by constructing δ for arbitrarily small ε, or proving that for some ε, δ does not exist.

So my question is:
Is there a function that one can not construct or disprove the existence of δ for ε?

Comment: Yeah - those functions whose limit at $c$ doesn't exist.

Comment: thanks, but people prove "the limit at c doesn't exist" by disproving the existence of δ. So for those functions, one can disprove the existence of δ.

Answer (score 2):

Take any statement $P$ that is logically undecidable, that is, it is not possible to either prove or disprove $P.$

Define a function $f$ as follows:

$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
0 & \text{if $x$ is rational or $P$ is true} \\
1 & \text{if $x$ is irrational and $P$ is false}.
\end{cases}
$$

Then $f$ is continuous at $0$ (in fact, $f(x)=0$ everywhere) if $P$ is true,
but $f$ is not continuous at $0$ if $P$ is false.
In one case it would be easy to construct $\delta$ and in the other it would be easy to show no such $\delta$ exists for $0 < \epsilon < 1.$
But it is impossible to prove which case holds, so we are unable to construct a suitable $\delta$ and unable to show it does not exist.

---

Basically, your question is, "Are there problems that cannot be solved?" And the answer is, "Yes."

Comment: Thanks, you construct a function that connects to some undecidable function, it's inspiring, but not satisfying to me. Because one doesn't know the value of f(x) for all x. You are right with the last sentence, except that the "problems" here are just the continuity of any R2R function that gives a y with an x. My motivation is that, literally, there is a space between "prove" and "disprove", why does not this space appear (so far?) among the real functions.

Comment: What do you mean by "real" functions? Functions from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$ (the usual math definition)? Functions you've seen already in a textbook? The number of functions is an uncountable infinite number; practically all functions cannot even be described as well as the function I described above. The ones we can actually work with are a vanishingly small subset of all possible functions. The ones you would see during two semesters of calculus are an even much smaller subset of that small subset.

Comment: You might want to make $P$ an "open question" instead of "logically undecidable." Then the function $f$ defined as above is (probably) logically decidable, just very, very difficult to prove continuous or not.

Comment: How about this: for all functions that for any real x, f(x) is a real number that you can tell, not describe with other functions.

Comment: Or, with the function you constructed, could you give me an example of logically undecidable P that you can tell f(sqrt(2)) equals to 0 or 1.